# How to check elements in two different lists in python with condition?

Tags: list, python-2.7

Example:

```
a = ['a', 'c']      # first test
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a = ['a','e']       # second test
b = ['a','b','c']
list_final = compare(a,b) # we tried this not working
```

We have to create the following logic: if both elements of list `a` are in list `b`, it will proceed further, whereas if one element of list `a` is not available in list `b` it has to terminate. Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: What do you think should happen for `compare(['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a'])`?

Comment: Also, `compare(['a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'])`

Comment: `a=['a,'c'] b=['a','b','c','d']` this is correct because all element in a list matching in b list....`a=['a','e'] b=['a','b','c','d']` this is not correct because 'e' is not in b list @thefourtheye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def compare(x, y):
    "Return True if all the elements of x are in y, False otherwise"
    return all([item in y for item in x])
```

You can use the function above in conditional branching:

```
def wrapper(x, y):
    if compare(x, y):
        print 'Proceed further'
    else:
        print 'Break'
```

Give this code a try to figure out how it works:

```
>>> a1 = ['a','c']
>>> a2 = ['a','e']
>>> b = ['a','b','c']
>>> wrapper(a1, b)
Proceed further
>>> wrapper(a2, b)
Break
```

Comment: awesome  but we tried like this...your code is like pythonic way                                                                                            `a=['a','b']`
`b=['a','b','c']`
`flag = True`
`for i in a:`
    `if i in b:`
        `pass`
    `else:`
        `flag = False`
`if flag == True:`
    `print a`
`else:`
    `print "False" `

Comment: The comprehension ``[item in a1 for item in b]`` returns ``[True, True]`` whereas ``[item in a2 for item in b]`` returns ``[True, False]``. You should only proceed if **all** the elements of the returned comprehension are ``True``. This is why you need to use the built-in function all(). Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Make this as your compare method using `all` keyword of python :-

```
def compare(x,y):
    if all(i in y for i in x):
        print "Proceed"
        # Call the next code piece
    else:
        print "Terminate"
        break
```

Now pass `a` as `x` and `b` as `y` in the call :-

```
>>> # Test 1
>>> a = ['a', 'c']      # first test
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> compare(a, b)
Proceed

>>> # Test 2
>>> a = ['a', 'e']      # first test
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> compare(a, b)
Terminate
```